# How to generate a polygonal chart

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I'm developing an android application in which I want to show a set of aptitude's person and a numeric rating associated to each one of them.

Currently, my approach is a `ListView` where each row shows a `TextView` with the name of the aptitude and a `RatingBar` representing its value. The problem is, I have to show around 6-10 rows which in most cases fills the screen and from my point of view, it's not an elegant solution.

I came out with the idea of representing the info as a key-value set in a polygonal chart. Something like this:

[image: polygonal chart example]

I'm guessing I will need to be working with `Canvas`, which I have never did before. I would like to ask for a first steps of how would you get into this approach (if there's models to be defined, which android apis to use) or even better, if there's any library to get something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

---

it has Radar Chart (spider web chart) which is highly customizable. 
you get something like this [image]